# sql dates quater of specific year

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am trying to create a report that gives me number to an event that occurred in the week, month and quarter of a specific date.
I have been able to so so for weeks and months but having issue with quarter. I want results for quarter of that specific year- like in the example below for 2016 only.

For example

```
declare @date date set @date = '2016/02/30'    

select case_id, event_date  
from #total  
WHERE datepart(quarter, event_DATE) = datepart(quarter, @date)   
order by 2
```

when I use this code it gives me result for not only 2016 but also for same quater of 2015,2014 (previous years).

```
case_id         event_date  
1234        1986-02-06  
5567        2014-01-04   
3456       2015-03-11     
6378       2016-02-23    
4789        2016-02-06  
6782        2016-01-04   
2346       2016-03-11     
9098       2016-02-23
```

what I want: only for 2016 and not previous years.

```
case_id         event_date  
4789        2016-02-06  
6782        2016-01-04   
2346       2016-03-11     
9098       2016-02-23
```

Comment: You need to match `DatePart(year, …)` as well. Q1 etc. appears in every year.

Comment: Though in general you want to [avoid functions in your `where` clause](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3204/avoid-using-functions-in-where-clause/) altogether.  Build a dates table and `join` onto that.

Comment: thanks for the edits.

Comment: @Richard can you please be more clear? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try adding a condition for the year:

```
[...] AND datepart(year, event_DATE) = datepart(year, @date)
```

You query would look something like

```
SELECT case_id, event_date  
FROM #total  
WHERE datepart(quarter, event_DATE) = datepart(quarter, @date)
AND datepart(year, event_DATE) = datepart(year, @date)
ORDER BY 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @date date set @date = '2016/02/30'    

select case_id, event_date  
from #total  
WHERE datepart(quarter, event_DATE) = datepart(quarter, @date) 
AND datepart(YYYY,event_DATE) = '2016'  
order by 2
```

Comment: Use the dynamic code that @nbouchet advises, it is better than what I have done there.